# Is it possible to add on to a value (int) already defined in a key for a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I'm trying to add a single value (+50 to gold) to key in an already populated dictionary. Is it possible to do so without changing all the values in the dictionary?

```
inventory = {'gold' : 500,
'pouch' : ['flint', 'twine', 'gemstone']
```

I saw that I can modify all the values in a dictionary but have found nothing for modifying just one. Was just wondering if that was possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just access the value by key `gold` and add `50` to it using `+=`:

```
>>> inventory = {'gold' : 500, 'pouch' : ['flint', 'twine', 'gemstone']}
>>> inventory['gold'] += 50
>>> inventory
{'pouch': ['flint', 'twine', 'gemstone'], 'gold': 550}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do it.

```
inventory['gold'] += 50
```

This is similar to:

```
inventory['gold'] = inventory['gold'] + 50
```

It will only change the value of 'gold'.